# matching words in strings with variables in R

Tags: r, string, comparison

I have a data set, like the following:

```
cp<-data.frame("name"=c("billy", "jean", "jean", "billy","billy", "dawn", "dawn"), 
"answer"=c("michael jackson is my favorite", "I like flowers", "flower is red","hey michael",
"do not touch me michael","i am a girl","girls have hair"))
```

Every variable called *name* has a string attached to it, stored in the variable *answer*. I would like to find out what specific words, or parts of words, or whole sentences, in the *answer* variable, that is common for the different names in *name*:

For example, the name `"billy"` would have `"michael"` connected to it.

EDIT:

A data frame with following variables called `ddd`:

```
name: debby                 answer: "did you go to dallas?"
name: debby                 answer: "debby did dallas"

function(name=debby,data=ddd) {...} ,
```

which gives output `"did debby dallas"`.

Comment: There's no "michael" in the first column...

Comment: @VincentGuillemot, yes there is.

Comment: @ErosRam, your first desired output is easy to achieve, the problem is that it is hard to identify plurals without external NLP packages, which can get messy

Comment: Could you please be more specific about what you want (an example), and also post the desired result.

Comment: @DavidArenburg : that is too bad. I was interested in plurals as well. And maybe even match words spelled incorrectly to the correctly spelled equivalent.

Comment: @RichardScriven: DMT gave me what I wanted in his answer. But I was also looking for plurals. Basically anything in the answers that is equal :)

Comment: Okay, that's fine.  But what about the other users that might have the same issue as you but won't know this question could help them solve their problem?  Also, per your comment on DMT's answer, you are not getting more answers because it's difficult to determine what you want.

Comment: @RichardScriven I though I was clear enough with my michael example, but I shall write another example if it can make things clearer :)

Comment: Why your output (in the edit) won't give you `"dallas"` too? Anyway, I've written a general solution when I saw your question, but wasn't sure what to do with it as it also don't deal with plurals. I can post it too if you want

Comment: @DavidArenburg Yes you are correct, Dallas too, thank you. If you think it might be useful, yes please post that too :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a (not very efficient) function I've made that uses `pmatch` in order to match partial matches. The problem with it that it will also match `a` and `am` or `i` and `is` because they are also very close.

```
freqFunc <- function(x){
  temp <- tolower(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), " ")))
  temp2 <- length(temp)
  temp3 <- lapply(temp, function(x){
    temp4 <- na.omit(temp[pmatch(rep(x, temp2), temp)])
    temp4[length(temp4) > 1]
  })
  list(unique(unlist(temp3))) 
}

library(data.table)
setDT(cp)[, lapply(.SD, freqFunc), by = name, .SDcols = "answer"]
#     name              answer
# 1: billy             michael
# 2:  jean i,is,flower,flowers
# 3:  dawn     a,am,girl,girls
```

If you satisfied with just exact matches, this can be very simplified and improve performance (I also added `tolower` so it will match different cases too)

```
freqFunc2 <- function(x){
  temp <- table(tolower(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), " "))))
  list(names(temp[temp > 1]))
}

library(data.table)
setDT(cp)[, lapply(.SD, freqFunc2), by = name, .SDcols = "answer"]
#     name  answer
# 1: billy michael
# 2:  jean        
# 3:  dawn
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you use temp2 in "rep(x, temp2)"? Would not rep(x, 2) work fine?

This seems to make the coder a lot faster.

Comment: `temp2` is the length of `temp` and it varies, it is not always equals to 2

Comment: lapply will take every element in vector '"temp"', one by one, and use it in the specified function within the 'lapply' function. The specified function uses 'pmatch', and pmatch matches every element of 'temp', with all of the elements of 'temp'. In my eyes, we do not need to repeat the 'temp' vector 'temp2' times. Only 2 times is necessary, right? 

I assume that the argument in 'freqFunc' is a string including all of the answers from the same name

Comment: What I am trying to say is that setting `temp2` equal to 2 seems to be sufficient when we are only interested in matches, and not the number of matches.

Answer (score 1):

With the caveat of understanding correctly, I think this is what you''re looking for.  Doesn't handle plurals of words though, as David mentioned.  This just finds words that are exactly the same.

```
billyAnswers<-cp$answer[cp$name=="billy"]
#output of billyAnswers
#[1] "michael jackson is my favorite" "hey michael"                   
#[3] "do not touch me michael"
```

Now we get all the words

```
allWords<-unlist(strsplit(billyAnswer, " "))
#outputvof allWords
# [1] "michael"  "jackson"  "is"       "my"       "favorite" "hey"     
# [7] "michael"  "do"       "not"      "touch"    "me"       "michael"
```

We can find the common ones

```
common<-allWords[duplicated(allWords)]
#output of common
#[1] "michael" "michael"
```

Of course there are two michaels because there are multiple instances of michael in billy's answers!  So let's pair it down once more.

```
unique(common)
#[1] "michael"
```

And there you go, apply that to all names and you got it.

For jean and dawn, there are no common words in their answers, so this method returns two character vectors of length 0

```
#jean's words
#[1] "I"       "like"    "flowers" "flower"  "is"      "red" 

#dawn's words
#[1] "i"     "am"    "a"     "girl"  "girls" "have"  "hair"
```

Comment: Actually my guess that the OP will want to consider "flower" and "flowers" as common. Same for "girl" and "girls"

Comment: Yes, I didn't handle that (made ssure to make that clear so there wasn't any confusion), so if that's what the OP wants hopefully someone will step in!

Comment: @DMT thank you for your contribution. I appreciate that. I upvoted. Will accept answer if I do not get anything else. I did want plurals, but if it is not possible without making things horribly complex, I shall be satisfied. :)

Comment: @ErosRam yes I think I have an idea of a bit of a hacky way to do it with partial matching, won't be particularly efficient but if I've got time I'll post it